# Is it possible to display custom icon in Visual Studio status bar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I am aware of displaying custom text in Visual Studio status bar using [IVSStatusBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsstatusbar.aspx) interface. I have even [blogged](http://geekswithblogs.net/onlyutkarsh/archive/2013/08/11/using-visual-studio-status-bar-in-your-extensions.aspx) about it.

However, I have requirement to display custom  icon on the Visual Studio status bar. Similar to what Resharper does to display solution errors. On clicking the icon, it also pops-up a context menu.

[image: Resharper Icon]

So, **How can I display a custom icon in Visual Studio status bar, and if possible display a menu also on clicking it?**. An example will help.

The Animation method of IVSStatusBar already display icons, but uses predefined icons defined in [Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.constants.aspx). Is it possible to have custom icons and pass to Animation method?

On exploring the SDK, I found that [IVSStatusBarUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsstatusbaruser.aspx) interface can be used to display custom information when the window implementing that interface is displayed. But I am not sure whether that interface can be used to display custom icon.

Answer (score 5):

There is no published API for that kind of status bar extensibility. In one of my own extensions (PerfWatson Monitor), I locate the status bar element by searching the WPF visual tree, using a recursive search and `VisualTreeHelper`, descending from `Application.Current.MainWindow` looking for the resize gripper in the bottom right - a child element with the `Name` property set to 
`"ResizeGripControl"`. When I've found the gripper, I look at its parent (it should be a `DockPanel`) and insert my control in there. Note that, as your screenshot shows, Resharper is known to employ a similar trick, so you'll have to come up with a strategy that works with and without Resharper installed. Also note that some pieces of the status bar (the text, the line/col information and any animations) run in their own UI thread, so be careful if your control ends up there.

I notice you also ask about extending the existing animations. Yes, you can supply your own animations via a bitmap strip of 16x16 frames. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/fef208e7-b79d-4a0c-94fe-e6861196e1f5/#ba47b61c-77a8-46c8-aa10-a04211312e6c for an example. Unfortunately, this won't allow a clickable menu.